# Magento2 giving preg_match error while running setup upgrade command

Tags: magento2

I am doing a fresh magento2 v-2.4.5-p1 installation while doing `bin/magento s:up` i am getting an error.

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 25 ...vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/SqlVersionProvider.php on line 91
```

I have edited the file **app/etc/di.xml** to use my current MariaDB version.

```
<item name="MariaDB-(10.2-10.10)" xsi:type="string">^10\.[2-10]\.></item>
```

My MariaDB version is : 10.10.2-MariaDB.

and PHP version is : php@8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your app/etc/di.xml
change line 1856
to

```
<item name="MariaDB-(10.2-10.11)" xsi:type="string">^10\.([2-9]|10|11)\.</item>
```

or creat simple module to change
thank you
solution for magento 2.4.5

Comment: Thank you but i already solved it. with same solution.